# GHashTable vs std::tr1::unordered_map

Tags: c++, hashtable

Has anyone experienced with both GHashTable and std::tr1::unordered_map? I want to know which one to use and which one is more recommended. I couldn't find anything really useful online.

Thanks,

Comment: I believe a site called "google" might help you: http://incise.org/hash-table-benchmarks.html. Second result after searching "GHashTable unordered_map"

Comment: Google is cool ;-)... It just didn't happen to see this link... thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

I have a preference for standard library containers and tools when they will work.  This makes software more portable.  So on that basis I would go with std::tr1::unordered_map or better yet, I would use C++11 and go with std::unordered_map (if you have a suitable compiler and can use C++11) which is essentially the same as the tr1 container but has some additional speedups.

Finally, as one can see from the link above from @mfontanini unordered_map is pretty fast compared to many implementations.